# What can be said about the positive definite matrix with the structure: $\Lambda^T B \Lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following matrix: $H = \Lambda^T B \Lambda$, where $B$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries on the diagonal and $\Lambda$ is an invertible stochastic matrix with entries in each row adding up to $1$. Also all entries in $\Lambda$ are positive.

Clearly, $H$ is a positive definite matrix. Can we say something more about $H$? For example, we know that not any positive definite matrix can be represented this way (a PD matrix can have negative entries). But then, what properties a positive definite matrix should have to be represented this way?

Here is the context where this matrix appears. Let $H_{k} = \Lambda_{k}^{T} B_{k} \Lambda_{k}$ for $k=1,2$ be the matrices with the properties described above. Let $Q_{k}$ be the diagonal matrices with their diagonal entries $q_{k,ii}$ being the sums of the corresponding rows of matrix $\Lambda_{k}^{T} B_{k}$, i.e., $q_{k,ii} = \sum_{n} \lambda_{k,ni} b_{k,nn}$. Observe that elements in each row (and column) of $H_{k}$ also add up to $q_{k,ii}$:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j} h_{k,ij} = \sum_{j} \sum_{n} \lambda_{k,ni}\lambda_{k,nj}b_{k,nn} = \sum_{n} \lambda_{k,ni}\left( \sum_{j}\lambda_{k,nj} \right) b_{k,nn} = \sum_{n} \lambda_{k,ni} b_{k,nn} = q_{k,ii}.
\end{equation*}
Consider the following matrices: $A_{k} = H_{k}^{-1} \left( Q_{k} - H_{k} + Q_{k} - \Lambda_{k}^T B_{k} \right)$. Observe that the matrix $\left( Q_{k} - H_{k} + Q_{k} - \Lambda_{k}^T B_{k} \right)$ is an $M0$-matrix: elements in each row add up to zero, it has positive diagonal and negative off-diagonal entries. Let $\hat{A}_{k}$ be the matrices $A_{k}$ with the last rows and columns removed. Then I can show that $\det\left(\hat{A}_{k} \right) > 0$. I need to show that $\det\left(\hat{A}_{1} + \hat{A}_{2} \right) > 0$ and I haven't succeeded so far.

Comment: There are positive definite matrices, which contain negative entries, thus it does not hold that any positive definite matrix can be written in the form $\Lambda^T B\Lambda$, with $\Lambda, B$ satisfying the conditions you mentioned.

Comment: True. I guess, my question is what properties a PD matrix has when it is represented using a multiplication of stochastic matrices...